# Проблема с Cors в IE: not found in the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net

При использовании русских доменов получаю ошибку

> not found in the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Но это связано только с IE. Chrome и другие браузеры отрабатывают хорошо.

Сайт тест.головинский.рф. Проект на asp.net core.

Comment: Версия IE? И [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44723900/5752652) пишут, что нужно добавлять домены в доверенную зону.

Comment: @AK, где вот тут? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Вот тут вот на stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ребята, извините, моя вина. Я не сказал что использую asp.net Core. Cors настроен в проекте верно. Все браузеры отрабатывают на ура, но только не от Microsoft.

Comment: О какой версии IE идет речь? попробуй использовать не _тест.головинский.рф_, а его [PunyCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) -> _xn--e1aybc.xn--b1abqafeesfb0b.xn--p1ai_

Comment: Спасибо ребята что отвечаете. Версия IE 17... Я пробовал использовать вместо домена его PunyCode? но ни чего не вышло.